# unity facebook sdk get profile picture using www not working

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine, unityscript, facebook-unity-sdk

i am trying to get facebook profile photo by using facebook sdk

when I used this code it was working fine but suddenly second day url was not downloading.
url download completed is not printing, and it is showing no error.

```
private IEnumerator getProfilePicture()
{
    Debug.Log("Here  to get profile picture");

    WWW url = new WWW("https" + "://graph.facebook.com/" + FB.UserId + "/picture?type=square"); 

    yield return url;

    Debug.Log("url download completed");
    Texture2D textFb2 = new Texture2D(url.texture.width, url.texture.height, TextureFormat.ARGB32, false);

    Sprite sprite = Sprite.Create(url.texture, new Rect(0, 0, url.texture.width, url.texture.height), new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f), 32);
    spriteToDisplay.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = sprite;
}
```

Comment: It works for me - are you sure you are calling it with StartCoroutine(getProfilePicture()); ?

Comment: yup i tried with StartCoroutine(getProfilePicture()); and StartCoroutine("getProfilePicture"); both plus i tried with different facebook appid but it is not printing url download completed

Comment: http://download.unity3d.com/webplayer/images/unity-icon-big.jpg - giving this string in www field works fine

Comment: @GameDev, is this happening to all users? have you tried the same call on a browser? you may not have access to the user's /picture anymore

Comment: facebook give access to basic profile bydefault :public_profile
Provides access to a person's basic information, including first name, last name, profile picture, gender and age range. This permission is approved by default.(copied from facebook app). and yes if i enter that url to browser it is giving my profile picture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And finally after struggling for days i found the answer, and what i got is kind of strange..

when i use the same code without changing any thing , no check nothing and run in to android device it worked fine ,

it just had one pre-requirement that my phone **should be connected to packet data** and **not to wi-fi**...

one thing should be noted that there is no restriction on wi-fi network and i can use facebook through wi-fi network... plus score , name and other things are working over wi-fi.....its only that if i want to profile picture to be downloaded i have to connect my phone through packet data

Comment: Most likely you are getting a different upstream proxy over cellular then over wifi. That's why you get different results.

Answer (score 1):

The request you are sending to Facebook results in a 302 redirection to the image stored in Facebook's CDN. The reason it is not working for you is that Unity's WWW class has never supported 302 redirection properly.

It may be that it worked for a day or so because a resource hadn't propogated to the CDN network, but once it had you can no longer download it.

The 302 can be seen using curl:

```
$ curl https://graph.facebook.com/zuck/picture?type=square -I
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Location: https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-xfa1/v/t1.0-1/c14.4.153.153/s50x50/1939620_10101266232851011_437577509_n.jpg?oh=6b6cd8460210e1de160cf8a6056df416&oe=550D5F6C&__gda__=1429858477_b29a956770b6173d71cb28eb35fa99e6
Facebook-API-Version: v1.0
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Pragma: no-cache
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
X-FB-Rev: 1534884
Cache-Control: private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Expires: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT
X-FB-Debug: 3+McQVKq40Qa/6hLThwOwQTXP5dpENQqA5FvbX3elTkVxKsEw6ISvJG0eh0V5wVTUjC4fkmuZ1coTCDm2rLTZg==
Date: Wed, 17 Dec 2014 13:33:13 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 0
```

One suggestion is to use [Uniweb](http://u3d.as/content/different-methods/uni-web/1Cw) library which does handle 302's.

Or handle the 302 yourself, extract the Location response header and send another WWW request. (But reponse headers are not available on all platforms).

Comment: thank you for responding. I am not allowed to have paid plugin..is there any other option?

Comment: in that case, you can add a check to your code if the response had a new location to go to with var redirection = www.responseHeaders["LOCATION"] (Note: must be in uppercase). If so, the do another www request  www = new WWW(redirection); yield return www;

Comment: hey thanks for reply, if possible can you write me a sample code. working with www is really new to me, and things are not coming in to my head at all

Comment: You've pretty much know everything using WWW as you posted. I use the Unity docs as reference: http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.html Just add my code above to check for location and that's it!

Comment: by using this                                       Debug.Log("Here  to get profile picture");
WWW url = new WWW("https" + "://graph.facebook.com/" + FB.UserId + "/picture?type=square");
        var redirection = url.responseHeaders["LOCATION"];
        Debug.Log("Responce of redirection " + redirection);
        yield return url;
        Debug.Log("url download completed"); - it is giving me error of www is not finished downloading yet.

Comment: Make sure you do it in a co-routine and you yield on www to wait until it is completed the download.

Comment: WWW www = new WWW(url);
yield return www;

if( www.responseHeaders.ContainsKey( "LOCATION" ) ){

    var redirection = www.responseHeaders[ "LOCATION" ];

    WWW wwwRe = new WWW( redirection );
    yield return wwwRe;
    callback( wwwRe.texture, userID );
}else{
   callback( www.texture, userID );
  }

I tried this code and still on the simulator it works on the device i get nothing. can you help me please what I do wrong? thanks.